# Flex NetStream.Step doesn't work per-frame

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming, flash-media-server

I've got a Flex 4 project, and a FMS 4 (Flash Media Server) server that streams mp4 streams from recorded f4v files.

My video control is a subclass of Spark/components/VideoPlayer, and I have buttons for stepping back and forth in a video. We need to be able to see each frame individually but it seems to only update the image every four or five frames (it varies, even within the same video).

Here's the code, nothing particularly advanced:

```
public function stepButtonClick(direction:int, shiftDown:Boolean):void {
    //Step forwards or backwards
    //NOTE Steps 10 frames if the shift key is held
    var stream:NetStream = getStream();

    if (stream) {
        stream.step(shiftDown ? (direction * 10) : direction);
    }
}
```

Any idea what I can do to fix or debug this issue? Could it be that it's only showing I-frames (keyframes)?

Answer (score 0):

Stepping can only be done to a keyframe, so if you want this make sure you set keyframes close enough, but remember these have a tremendous impact on file size.

Also, RTMP streaming is not nearly as good at this as as Http Dynamic Streaming...

Good luck!  If you need further help let me know...

~ JT